# Why is passing pointer-pointers not motivated in Cocoa development?

Tags: objective-c, performance, pointers

When I pass a string the Apple-style way to a function and test it a billion times it takes ~ `42,001` seconds:

```
- (void)test:(NSString *)str {
    NSString *test = str;

    if (test) {
        return;
    }
}

NSString *value = @"Value 1";

NSLog(@"START");
for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    [self test:value];
}
NSLog(@"END");
```

But then passing the pointer it's pointer as a value (assuming my `test` function will be read-only style) like so:

```
- (void)test:(NSString **)str {
    NSString *test = *str;

    if (test) {
        return;
    }
}

NSLog(@"START");
for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    [self test:&value];
}
NSLog(@"END");
```

..only takes ~`26,804` seconds.

Why does Apple promote the first example as normal practice, while the latter seems to perform so different?

I read about the `Toll-Free Bridging` that Foundation applies, but if the difference is relatively so big, what's the added value? A whole application that would run a factor of more than 100% faster by just upgrading some major function arguments like this, then isn't that a considerable flaw by Apple, in their way of instructing how to build apps in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use the `NSString **` syntax, as that suggests that the method you're calling can change what `value` points to. You would never do that unless this is really what was taking place.

The simple `NSString *` example may be taking longer because in the absence of any optimization, the `NSString *` rendition is probably adding/removing of a strong references to `value` when the method is called and returns.

If you turn on optimization, the behavior changes. For example, when I used `-Os` "Fastest, Smallest" build setting, the `NSString *` rendition was actually faster than the `NSString **` one. And even if the performance was worse, I wouldn't write the code that exposed me to all sorts problems down the line just because it was was 0.0000152 seconds faster per call. I'd find other ways to optimize the code.

To quote Donald Knuth:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. [Emphasis added]

The goal is always to write code whose functional intent is clear, whose type handling is safest and then, where possible, use the compiler's own internal optimization capabilities to tackle the performance issues. Only sacrifice the code readability and ease of maintenance and debugging when it's absolutely essential.

Comment: Thanks again Rob! As discussed before, totally makes sense and thanks again for your insights.